# How to speed up this python script with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a script that get data from a dataframe, use those data to make a request to a website, using fuzzywuzzy module find the exact href and then runs a function to scrape odds. I would speed up this script with the multiprocessing module, it is possible?

```
                           Date       HomeTeam         AwayTeam
0  Monday 6 December 2021 20:00        Everton          Arsenal
1  Monday 6 December 2021 17:30         Empoli          Udinese
2  Monday 6 December 2021 19:45       Cagliari           Torino
3  Monday 6 December 2021 20:00         Getafe  Athletic Bilbao
4  Monday 6 December 2021 15:00  Real Zaragoza            Eibar
5  Monday 6 December 2021 17:15      Cartagena         Tenerife
6  Monday 6 December 2021 20:00         Girona          Leganes
7  Monday 6 December 2021 19:45          Niort         Toulouse
8  Monday 6 December 2021 19:00      Jong Ajax         FC Emmen
9  Monday 6 December 2021 19:00        Jong AZ        Excelsior
```

Script

```
  df = pd.read_excel(path)

  dates = df.Date
  hometeams = df.HomeTeam
  awayteams = df.AwayTeam

  matches_odds = list()

  for i,(a,b,c) in enumerate(zip(dates, hometeams, awayteams)):
      try:
        r = requests.get(f'https://www.betexplorer.com/results/soccer/?year={a.split(" ")[3]}&month={monthToNum(a.split(" ")[2])}&day={a.split(" ")[1]}')
      except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        sleep(10)
        r = requests.get(f'https://www.betexplorer.com/results/soccer/?year={a.split(" ")[3]}&month={monthToNum(a.split(" ")[2])}&day={a.split(" ")[1]}')
      
      soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
      f = soup.find_all('td', class_="table-main__tt")

      for tag in f: 
          match = fuzz.ratio(f'{b} - {c}', tag.find('a').text)
          hour = a.split(" ")[4]
          if hour.split(':')[0] == '23':
              act_hour = '00' + ':' + hour.split(':')[1]
          else:
              act_hour = str(int(hour.split(':')[0]) + 1) + ':' + hour.split(':')[1]
          if match > 70 and act_hour == tag.find('span').text:
              href_id = tag.find('a')['href']

              table = get_odds(href_id)
              matches_odds.append(table)
          
      print(i, ' of ', len(dates))
```

PS: The `monthToNum` function just replace the month name to his number

Comment: If your program is IO bound but not CPU heavy, you can use Threading module. But please refer to documentation of these two modules, they are really nicely written, maybe you won't have to ask that kind of question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you make a function of your loop body with inputs i, a, b and c. Then, you create a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and submit this function with the proper arguments (i, a, b, c) to the pool.

```
import multiprocessing

df = pd.read_excel(path)

dates = df.Date
hometeams = df.HomeTeam
awayteams = df.AwayTeam

matches_odds = list()

def fetch(data):
    i, (a, b, c) = data
    try:
        r = requests.get(f'https://www.betexplorer.com/results/soccer/?year={a.split(" ")[3]}&month={monthToNum(a.split(" ")[2])}&day={a.split(" ")[1]}')
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        sleep(10)
        r = requests.get(f'https://www.betexplorer.com/results/soccer/?year={a.split(" ")[3]}&month={monthToNum(a.split(" ")[2])}&day={a.split(" ")[1]}')
      
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    f = soup.find_all('td', class_="table-main__tt")

    for tag in f: 
        match = fuzz.ratio(f'{b} - {c}', tag.find('a').text)
        hour = a.split(" ")[4]
        if hour.split(':')[0] == '23':
            act_hour = '00' + ':' + hour.split(':')[1]
        else:
            act_hour = str(int(hour.split(':')[0]) + 1) + ':' + hour.split(':')[1]
        if match > 70 and act_hour == tag.find('span').text:
            href_id = tag.find('a')['href']

            table = get_odds(href_id)
            matches_odds.append(table)
          
    print(i, ' of ', len(dates))

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    num_processes = 20
    with multiprocessing.Pool(num_processes) as pool:
        pool.map(fetch, enumerate(zip(dates, hometeams, awayteams)))
```

Besides, `multiprocessing` is not the only way to improve the speed. Asynchronous programming can be used as well and is probably better for this scenario, although `multiprocessing` does the job, too - just want to mention that.

If carefully read the [Python multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), then it'll be obvious.

Comment: I tried your code but I got this `RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.`

Comment: I modified my answer. Try `if __name__ == '__main__': ` before `multiprocessing.Pool`. I haven't tested this code, but I haven't got this issue on a similar code on Ubuntu/Python3.6.

Comment: Still error `i, a, b, c = data
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)`

Comment: Then, probably have to write `i, (a, b, c) = data`